# Javascript - How to reference object nested values using an array as reference

Tags: javascript

I am building some forms that need to handle entities that might have nested objects. So I need the interface to accept as the field key either a string or an array of strings with each piece of the path to the value (like the example below).

```
const obj = {
    name: "John",
    role: {
        id: 1,
        name: "admin"
    }
}

const key1 = 'name'
const key2 = ['role', 'name']

function getValueByKey (key, obj) {

    if (Array.isArray(key)) {
        //Get value if key is array.
    } else {

        return obj[key]
    }
}

console.log(getValueByKey(key1, obj))
//Should output "John"
console.log(getValueByKey(key2, obj))
//Should output "admin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by using the key at index zero for handing over a nested property of the given object.

```js
function getValueByKey(key, obj) {
    return Array.isArray(key) && key.length > 1
        ? getValueByKey(key.slice(1), obj[key[0]])
        : obj[key];
}

const
    obj = { name: "John", role: { id: 1, name: "admin" } },
    key1 = 'name',
    key2 = ['role', 'name'];

console.log(getValueByKey(key1, obj)); // "John"
console.log(getValueByKey(key2, obj)); // "admin"
```

An iterative approach

```js
function getValueByKey(key, obj) {
    return [].concat(key).reduce((o, k) => o[k], obj);
}

const
    obj = { name: "John", role: { id: 1, name: "admin" } },
    key1 = 'name',
    key2 = ['role', 'name'];

console.log(getValueByKey(key1, obj)); // "John"
console.log(getValueByKey(key2, obj)); // "admin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Lodash's get method. It does exactly what you want.

https://lodash.com/docs/#get

```
_.get(obj, 'name');
// => John
 
_.get(obj, "role.name");
// => admin
```

If you're unable to use lodash directly, you can always look at its implementation [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/get.js); it is as tried-and-tested as it gets.